# Formula for the number of partitions of 2N elements

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

We have a set $S$ of $2N$ distinct elements. I want to partition it into $N$ parts each containing 2 elements. My motivation is partitioning a group of people into pairs.

> What is the formula that gives the number of different partitions of $S$?

I prefer closed-form formula. If no such formula exists then asymptotic growth rate is fine.

**EDIT**: I received several answers. The formula seems hard to calculate. Hence, I am also interested in an *accurate* Stirling approximation of the formula.

I got this Stirling approximation: $\sqrt 2 (2N/e)^N$. Is this the most accurate approximation?

Comment: $\frac{(2N)!}{2^{N}N!} = (2N-1)(2N-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1$, sometimes written as $(2N-1)!!$.

Comment: Easy to prove. First choose the partner for 1, there are (2N-1) possibilities. Now choose the partner for the lowest remaining number, there are (2N-3) possibilities, and so on.

Comment: Very elegant, almagest!

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425250/in-how-many-ways-can-we-pair-ourselves).

Answer (score 1):

Why not repeatedly choose the 2 components for each partition in order, to get
$$
\binom{2N}{2} \times \binom{2N-2}{2} \times \ldots \times \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{2}
 = \prod_{k=1}^N \binom{2k}{2},
$$
which you can simplify since $\binom{n}{2} = n(n-1)/2$ to get
$$
\prod_{k=1}^N \binom{2k}{2} = \prod_{k=1}^N \frac{2k(2k-1)}{2} = \frac{(2N)!}{2^N}
$$

**UPDATE** To account for the fact that this is an ordered partition, divide by the overcount factor of $N!$ to get
$$
\frac{(2N)!}{N! \cdot 2^N} = (2N-1)!!,
$$
as was pointed out by Thomas Andrews in  a comment.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews fixed thanks

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, fixed thank you

Answer (score 1):

The desired number is

$$\frac{(2N)!}{N!\cdot2^N}$$

To get this, consider that there are $N!$ arrangements for every unordered partition.